# How to pick variable based on 2 different variables in JS

Tags: javascript, json, variables

Let's suppose there is a global variable in JS

```
var a = json // some json data in this variable
```

There are some more global variables in JS

```
var a_b = json // some json data in this variable
var a_c = json // some json data in this variable
var a_d = json // some json data in this variable
var a_e = json // some json data in this variable
```

Now in the JS file by default, I am showing a graph based on the JSON data present in variable "a" but on a certain condition I want to destroy the graph and then regenerate the graph based on the JSON data present in other global variables.

Now the issue is for determining which global variable's JSON data I should use to generate the graph I have to find out the name of the variable.

In my JS file, I have a local variable say "c" and it contains the value of what should come after "a_" in the global varaible. But I am not sure how to write the variable so that it refers to the global variable. 
I am writing it as `a_+c` but doesn't work and shows the error that a_ is not defined. I checked the variable "c" by console.log and it showed me the correct value what should come there.

So can anyone help me here to figure out on how to proceed on this one so that I can refer to the variable `a_b` if the value of "c" is "b".

Comment: You can define the values as properties of a plain object and use bracket notation

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this
`window['a_c']` 
this will give you global variable a_c

Comment: Thanks, I never used this before but today I did. I learned new thing today so many thanks for this.